# Xampp y MySQL - Problema para iniciar MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

gracias por tomarse el tiempo para leer esta pregunta. Intentare resumir:

1. Instale MySQL completo de la pagina de MySQL pero no me podia conectar a netbeans porque necesitaba el localhost, en este caso decidi usar xaamp que instale despues y creo que venia una instalacion propia de MySQL dentro del xampp.
2. Al principio todo bien, ya podia conectar las bd con netbeans y trabajar pero esta mañana que encendí el pc esto no funcionaba de ninguna forma, y me di cuenta que en las apps se estaban ejecutando 2 mysql en segundo plano, pero si finalizaba una la otra se iba.Esto me parecio muy raro porque en los videos que veia de youtube, solo tenian 1 solo "servicio" por lo que decidi desinstalar todo e instalar solo el xampp y el workbench.
3. Actualmenete funciona todo pero como el xampp instala todo solo, no pude ponerle una contraseña al mysql y ahora lo tengo sin contraseña. Investigando como colocarsela, me mandaron a ejecutar unos comandos en mysql.exe y he aqui el problema.

**No me abre mysql.exe**

Incluso intente meter la carpeta dentro del path de variables de entorno para poder llamarlo desde el cmd normal y me salió este error:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Lo que me parece raro porque yo en workbench cree una base de datos, le agregue registros con phpmyadmin y la vistualicé en netbeans... No se que sucede que no puedo acceder a ningun comando sql desde el cmd.

Quiero aclarar que en el path, escogi la carpeta bin del MySQL del xampp ya que no tengo otra instalacion dentro del pc.

Seguido de eso my servicio de MySQL80 en el administrador me aparece DETENIDO, y eso creo que quizas tiene que ver con que no encuentra el resto de los componentes de MYSQL o yo que se, el xampp no pesa casi nada mientras que la instalación que baje de la propia MYSQL pesaba 400mb (el doble del xampp).

Que solucion me pueden dar? Instalo el mysql solo ahora?

Recuerden que mi finalidad es tener el mysql funcionando con contraseña.

Muchas gracias

**ACTUALIZO**

El problema yace en que cuando se instala el xampp se usa el puerto 3306 del pc pero yo lo cambie al 3308, cambiando el registro del my.ini y por eso sale el error.

Si vuelvo a cambiar el puerto al 3306, el comando mysql funciona perfectamente.
**Entonces cual es la forma correcta de cambiar los puertos del mysql?**

Claro, sin perder los comandos cmd...